# Actualizar varios registros de una columna en una sola consulta SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Quiero reducir el número de UPDATEs que hago desde mi aplicación a la tabla `ventas` de mi base de datos. Este UPDATE envía un valor al registro de la columna `ordenadores`, siempre que coincidan con los valores pasados a `id` y `procesador`.
Tengo miles de registros con diferentes valores, por tanto acabo haciendo miles de UPDATEs era finalizar la tarea.

PHP

```
$valor_id = $_POST['id'];
$procesador = $_POST['procesador'];
$valor_n = $_POST['valor'];

$sql = "UPDATE ventas SET ordenadores = ".$valor_n." WHERE valor_id = ".$valor_id." AND procesador = ".$procesador."";

$result = $db_connection -> query($sql);
```

¿Es posible actualizar, en un solo UPDATE, diferentes filas con diferentes valores en la columna `ordenadores`?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Pablo, a esta pregunta le falta algo de información: si ésta es la segunda consulta, ¿cómo es la primera?¿y cómo se conectan las dos?¿Cómo sabes qué valor se tiene que asignar a qué columna?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, en el cliente tengo un `for` que recoge y envía, mediante AJAX, el `$valor_id` y un `$valor_id`. Esta petición llega al servidor para que ejecute la consulta SQL, que actualiza al BBDD.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro, voy a probar con `IN` y también con las `multi_query`. Un saludo.

Comment: Aunque para esos métodos vas a necesitar tener todos los valores de golpe, y por lo que comentas, parece que los mandas uno a uno

Comment: Por DIos, no se te ocurra poner este código en un servidor en producción!  Es totalmente vulnerable a ataques por "SQL injection", cualquier visitante puede borrarte la base de datos entera! Jamás (JAMÁS) hagas eso de tirarle a la DB un query armado así, concatenando datos que te llegan de un request. Usa prepared statements, SIN FALTA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes que nada y **MUY** importante: nunca armes una sentencia SQL en base a parámetros que se envían en el POST. Esto da lugar a problemas de [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Por lo tanto, siempre que se pasen parámetros a un SQL debería ser de la siguiente forma (utilizando [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE ventas SET ... WHERE id = :id');
$stmt->execute(array('id' => $valor_id));
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

En el ejemplo, el parámetro está en la variable `$valor_id` y lo representa el texto `:id` en la sentencia SQL.

Ahora, yendo al problema y dadas las condiciones que planteas tendría que responder que NO se puede realizar la operación que queres.

Como se mencionan en los comentarios de la pregunta, hay varias opciones para implementar, y dependen mucho de algunos datos más del problema que no se tienen para poder responder correctamente.

**Opción 1**

Si por ejemplo tuvieras una tabla parecida a la siguiente (llamémosle TablaX):

```
valor_id | procesador | valor_n
---------|------------|---------
xxx      | 'intel'    | yyy
aaa      | 'amd'      | bbb
```

podrías realizar algo como lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE ventas INNER JOIN TablaX
    ON ventas.valor_id = TablaX.valor_id AND ventas.procesador = TablaX.procesador
SET ventas.ordenadores = TablaX.valor_n
```

**Opción 2**

Otra opción sería agrupar valores. De esta manera no eliminarías todos los UPDATE pero tendrías menos. Por ejemplo, agrupar todos los update de 'intel', luego todos los de 'amd', etc.

Se me ocurre algo como lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE  ventas
SET     ordenadores = IF(valor_id = :valor_id1, :valor_n1, IF(valor_id = :valor_id2, :valor_n2, ..), ..),
WHERE   procesador = 'intel'
```

Utilizando algo del estilo, podrías pasar al `execute` un `array` con todos los posibles valores :valor_idi, :valor_ni (con i de 1 a N la cantidad de valores diferentes)

Seguramente haya más opciones pero como ya se mencionó, depende mucho del contexto del problema.

Espero haya sido de utilidad.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Claro, en una sola consulta puedes actualizar todos los campos que quieras de una tabla, por ejemplo:

```
UPDATE
 tabla
SET
 columna_1 = $value, columna_2 = $value, ... ,columna_n = $value
WHERE
 registro_en_comun_entre_filas = $valor_comun;
```

Espero resuelva tu duda, de todos modos me parece que tu pregunta esta incompleta y sería mejor si aportaras mas información, para dar una respuesta aun mas precisa.

Comment: lo primero, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. He reformulado la pregunta porque no estaba bien expresada.